# load a div content when sidebar is clicked in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

in my side bar i have home,about us,contact,... options.i have downloaded contact form plugins to display when contact sidebar option clicked.the form should display in left side like this link [wordpress][1]

[1]: http://logicresearchlabs.com/apps/Einsurance/contact1.php pls anyone guide me
how to customize the appearance menu.
if i click aboutus option i need to display another page in same div.like same that link.

Comment: can anyone give some idea

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Are you saying that you want a box to appear when someone clicks on a link in your sidebar with a contact form? Or are you struggling to get the form to appear at all in your theme?